# Can you use pre_get_posts outside of the main query?

Tags: wordpress, loops, hook

I'm new to WordPress and have been learning a lot about pre_get_posts lately. I understand the basic concept but am getting tripped up on a part of the documentation.

From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

*"Similarly, **pre_get_posts will not work if used in template files (e.g., archive.php)**, since they are called after the query has been completed."*

If you can't use it in template files, does that mean it's only good on index.php? If that's the case, why is there an example further down the page where pre_get_posts is used to change how an Archive displays?

I understand the power of pre_get_posts (over query_posts especially) but I'm having a hard time finding how it can be used many times on one site. Everything I see shows it being used once and only for the main Loop.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Files like `archive.php`, `category.php` are what WordPress calls *template files*. As the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) says, page templates generally have a high level of specificity. This would explain why the query is already initialized before template files are being called and therefore, `pre_get_posts` would miss it's point on template files.

You are able to show an archive without template files like `archive.php`, `category.php`, but `pre_get_posts` is - indeed - only meant to be called on the main query. This means that, if you add `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_callback_function')` to your `functions.php` file, it will alter the query site-wide. You can filter on specific page types inside the callback like so:

```
function my_callback_function($query){

   // Only if page type is category
   if(is_category()){
       $query->set('posts_per_page', 7);
   }

   // Always except for search page types
   if(!is_search()){
       $query->set('posts_per_page', 4);
   }
}
```

This way there's no need to call `pre_get_posts` twice.

If you want to perform multiple queries or specify an `archive.php` query, use instances of `WP_Query()`.

[More details](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762)

Comment: Thank you very much for that response, I really appreciate it. My only follow-up question would be this: if pre_get_posts is meant for the main query,

Comment: Thank you very much for that response, I really appreciate it. In my mind, most of the stuff I would develop on WP would have one main query, and then almost all other page requests would get passed to a template file where I could just use instances of WP_Query() like you said. Is there a scenario where you could use pre_get_posts more than once on the same site? Thanks again for your help, I tried to upvote your response but I don't have enough of a reputation for it to register yet.

Comment: This really got me thinking and I think I needed coffee... If you want to affect the main query on every type of page request, you have to put your `add_action` with callback function in your `functions.php` file, this actually works for e.g. `archive.php`, `category.php` and all sub-template files like `category-category-a.php`. You could create different callback functions in `functions.php` like if `is_category()`, then `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_category_callback_function')`, but to call it more than once would be redundant since it's only affecting one query, the main query.

Comment: This is terrific! Thanks for taking the time to craft this response, I have a much better understanding now.

Comment: Well glad to help! It's a very good question. Helps my understanding too. The information is all a bit vague on this topic.